# Tool Tips for macOS folders’ "Comments" field

Tags: macos, tooltip, finder

If notes (as opposed to simple category phrases) are written in the Comments field of macOS folders, is there a way using Automator (or whatever) to simply hover over the folder and see the contents of that field as a tooltip?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible to create such a hover effect.

However, you can just show the comments continuously:

```
View -> as List
View -> Show View Options
Show Columns: Comments (and maybe Tags?)
```

Or right click on the column headers to quickly change the columns being shown.

The advantage here (besides being possible) is that you do not have to wait for the tooltip to appear. Apologies, however, if this doesn't fit the workflow you had in mind.